# Definition of normed groups

Tags: group-theory, normed-spaces

I found the following definition of normed groups on [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/HomePage):

> A normed group is a pair $(G,\|\cdot\|)$ where $G$ is a group and $\|\cdot\|$ is a function $G\to\mathbb R$ satisfying the following conditions:
>
> - $\|g\|\geq 0$,
> - $\|g\|= 0$ if and only if $g=e$,
> - $\|g^{-1}\|=\|g\|$
> - $\|g_1g_2\|\leq \|g_1\|+\|g_2\|$.

I was wondering whether $G$ should be assumed to be commutative (as it is the case when $G$ is the group associated to a vector field), so I tried to verify a few results that one might want to hold. For example, it looks like the function
\begin{align}
G\times G&\to\mathbb R\\
(v,w)&\mapsto \|vw{}^{-1}\|
\end{align}
is indeed a metric, but I think that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty} v_n\lim_{n\to\infty}w_n=\lim_{n\to\infty} v_n w_n
\end{equation}
(where the two limits on the LHS are assumed to exist) requires commutativity. Since normed groups don't seem to be very popular yet (to my surprise, since the structure is enough to discuss series), I thought that this post could be used to discuss the following points:

- Necessity of commutativity (in particular I would appreciate a confirmation of my argument above).
- Suitability of the definition/necessity of further requirements to derive other results.

Comment: In group theory, the additive binary is normally reserved for abelian groups. But the definition itself can be restated for general groups, just use the multiplicative notation. Interesting examples come from geometric group theory.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_function#:~:text=Definition,metric%20and%20a%20filtered%20algebra. Also, note that nLab correctly uses the multiplicative notation in the definition of a normed group.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you for the comments. I decided to change the notation.

Comment: No, continuity does not require commutativity, although there are probably some examples where the multiplication is not continuous.

Comment: And, indeed, there are such examples.

Comment: Yes, the "usual" proof uses commutativity, but  one does not have to use the "usual" proof in all cases. Yes, we are talking about the same topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you should not assume that $G$ is commutative. There are many interesting situations when $G$ is a normed noncommutative group. In general, the multiplication may or may not be continuous.

Some examples:

1. $G$ is a group equipped with a generating set $S$, $d_S$ is the associated [word metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_metric) on $G$ and $|g|_S=d_S(1, g)$. Then the metric $d_S$ induces discrete topology on $G$ and, hence, the multiplication is continuous.
2. $G$ is a connected Lie group equipped with a left-invariant Riemannian metric which induces a left-invariant Riemannian distance function on $G$. This distance function induces the original topology on the Lie group $G$ and the multiplication is continuous.
3. Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $G$ is a group of isometries of $X$ (not necessarily the full group of isometries!) and $x\in X$ is a point whose $G$-stabilizer is trivial. Define $|g|_x:= d(x, gx)$. Then $|g|_x$ is a norm on $G$. In some cases, the multiplication is not continuous with respect to this norm. For instance, take $G=PSL(2, {\mathbb Q})$, $X$ is the hyperbolic plane and $G$ acts on $X$ by linear-fractional transformations preserving the hyperbolic metric. Take a generic point $x\in X$: It has trivial $G$-stabilizer. One can prove that the multiplication is discontinuous if we equip $G$ with topology induced by the norm $|g|_x$.

Lastly: It makes sense to eliminate the assumption that $|g|=0\Rightarrow g=1$ in the definition of a norm, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_function). Interesting examples again come from isometric group actions where we no longer require $x\in X$ to have trivial $G$-stabilizer.